# Is there a pure HTML5/Javascript alternative to jQuery.Callbacks() to implement a client side publish/subscribe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I could use [jQuery.Callbacks()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) for my client side publish and subscribe, but just like there is now [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) as an alternative to [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), I'm wondering if there is an alternative to this construct as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to implement some event logic to me, so ultimately you want to pair a `Key:string` to a `Value:function`.

Maybe try typing your object something like:

```js
myObject: {
 events : { key:string, callback:function }[]
}
```

Or event wrappers could be a good solution: See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget)